NPM Install Fails Windows_NT 10.0.22631
I am trying to run npm install in a project using Node.js v6.11.0 and NPM v3.10.10 because the project dependencies are outdated and require older versions of Node.js and NPM to work properly. However, I encounter the following error:

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\interrailing_packages\site\web\app\themes\rosiepress\node_modules.staging@types\cors-fab178ec\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\interrailing_packages\site\web\app\themes\rosiepress\node_modules.staging@types\cors-fab178ec\package.json'
npm ERR!

I've forced cleaned npm cache, Tried almost all of the solutions but still getting this error.
I'm using xampp with windows 11 and Node.js v6.11.0 and NPM v3.10.10
